# requests.request not working in Python 3 on Mac

Tags: python, python-requests

I am unable to use the requests library to run the following command:

```
import requests
requests.request("GET", "https://www.google.com/")
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'No such file or directory'), ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'no such file'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]
```

I'm running MacOS Sierra V 10.12.4 and using Python 3.

My openssl version is: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried updating the certs as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334357 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this answer helped me.

Installing the `certifi` module did the trick.

[urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error/42334357#42334357)